# How to open a particular slide in SharePoint presentation in a browser?

Tags: sharepoint, powerpoint

I want to open a presentation with a specific slide on. I know the slideId (4540) which is different from slide number(4). I tried the following urls but they always opens with slide 1.

```
https://xyzsolutions.sharepoint.com/sites/2021/Shared Documents/General/xyzfolder/xyzppt.pptx?&web=1&wdSlideId=4540

https://xyzsolutions.sharepoint.com/sites/2021/Shared Documents/General/xyzfolder/xyzppt.pptx?&web=1&wdSlideNumber=4
```

what is the correct URL to be used?

[Reference](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/open-an-o365-powerpoint-file-in-presentation-mode/9b922332-4198-46c8-b1ac-62fa9f3a123d)

Comment: AFAIK there is no such URL parameter. The "share URLs" are automatically generated, and basically contain some encoded string with no clear parameters like in your request. You can create share links using PowerPoint application itself (like explained below), or try doing that using SharePiont API (there are API methods to generate share links). Not sure if that API can make a slide link, but this might be the path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the link created by the Link to this Slide it contains &nav=eyJzSWQiOjI1OSwiY0lkIjozNzk4ODEzMTY1fQ or equivalent. If you decode the base64 string you get {"sId":259,"cId":3798813165} in the above example. I'm presuming sId in your case would be 4540 and the cId is defined for the particular powerpoint document. So `https://xyzsolutions.sharepoint.com/sites/2021/Shared Documents/General/xyzfolder/xyzppt.pptx?&web=1&nav=eyJzSWQiOjI1OSwiY0lkIjozNzk4ODEzMTY1fQ` (or equivalent should work)

Comment: I encoded only {"sId":259} and used nav=eyJzSWQiOjI1OX0. It works!

Answer (score -3):

In PowerPoint just right-click the slide you want assistance with and **choose Link to this Slide**.

[image]

Copy link and open it in your browser. It will pop up directly to this slide that you selected.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't serve my purpose. I am looking for the keyword in sharepoint url to show the exact slide we it opens in browser.

Comment: Please refrain from begging for votes here. Voting should be organic.

Comment: This is the sixth occasion of editing it out @Nikolay. Not being aware is fine, but there is a point where the addition of unwelcome copy+paste material appears to be wilful.

Comment: @halfer wow. sixth. Now I got it